# Issue in generating invoice using Stripe api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment, stripe-payments

I have integrated stripe API in my Rails application. I am facing a problem while getting invoiceitems from the JSON object.

Here i have provide you the details.

OS: CentOS
Ruby: v1.9.3
Rails: v3.0
Stripe: v1.8.3

cus_invoices = Stripe::Invoice.all(:customer=>customer.id, :count=>1).data

cus_invoices.each do |invoices|

invoiceitems = invoices.lines.invoiceitems.each do |lineitems|

Here, the transaction got successful and while returning the stripe ListObject, it throws an error as follows.

CLASS_NAME: NoMethodError 
MESSAGE: undefined method `invoiceitems' for #<Stripe::ListObject:0xbd9b13c>
TRACE: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/stripe-1.8.3/lib/stripe/stripe_object.rb:148:in`method_missing'

I didn't face this issue previously. Please let me know if any change in JSON object structure.

Kindly provide your support to solve this issue.

Thanks, 
Jude

Answer (score 0):

https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_customer_invoices shows the json

```
invoices.lines.each do |line|
  line_item = line.data
  line_item.id
  line_item.amount
end
```

You should check your API version (https://stripe.com/docs/api#versioning). If Stripe makes backward incompatible changes, it ups the API version.

Stripe sets the API version based on when you first use the API. So, if you recently got new API keys, it could use a new API version than when you originally started using it.

You can change your API version in your config initializer. Example:

```
Stripe.api_version = "2013-02-13"
```